# TensorFlow: Memory Allocation Alignment

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management

In TensorFlow, when I create a variable like this,

```
kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 2, 1],
                     dtype=tf.float32,stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
```

18 32-bit floating point variables are allocated in 72 (3*3*2*1*4) consecutive bytes. How can I align this variables in such a way that first 3*3 floating point values go to first 36 bytes of a 64 byte block and then the next 3*3 floating point values are allocated to the first 36 byte of the next 64 byte block. So far, I am only concerned with CPUs.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? It sounds a bit too low-level considering you are using the Python API.

Comment: I want to do this for one of my research project. I am using Python API because it is easier to explain the example. C++ solutions would work for me as well.